# “ps -U” does not list processes as expected

Tags: linux

Why doesn’t the `ps -U` command list the processes of the username `0x00`, on the contrary the root's are listed.

```bash
$ id     
uid=1000(0x00) gid=1000(0x00) groups=1000(0x00),3(sys),90(network),98(power),108(vboxusers),952(libvirt),956(docker),991(lp),998(wheel)
                                                                                                                                                                                      
$ whoami             
0x00
                                                                                                                                                                                      
$ ps -fu 0x00 | grep -i vbox | grep -v grep
root         468       2  0 09:02 ?        00:00:00 [iprt-VBoxTscThread]
                                                                                                                                                                                      
$ ps -fu 1000 | grep -i vbox | grep -v grep
0x00       35855    1332  0 10:44 ?        00:00:02 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxXPCOMIPCD
0x00       35861    1332  0 10:44 ?        00:00:05 /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSVC --auto-shutdown
```

I can create a username that starts with a number without error.

```bash
$ sudo useradd -M -s /usr/bin/nologin 0x01
                                                                                                                                                                                      
$ id 0x01
uid=1001(0x01) gid=1001(0x01) groups=1001(0x01)
```

Isn’t not recommended to set the username of Linux start with number?

Addition information on the kernel:

```bash
$ uname -a                  
Linux 0xff1 6.7.4-2-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Sat Feb 10 09:41:20 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: "*The username of Linux should not start with numerical numbers*" - Apparently that is not always a true statement. Some Linux distros do not enforce the rule that a username must begin with an alpha character. Is your post based entirely on this faulty premise (e.g. that a **ps** option is confused, and treats a username as a user ID)?  BTW what should a "*number*" be if not "*numeric*"?

Comment: @sawdust Sorry for the odd expression, English is not my native language. I edit the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can create a username that starts with a number without error.

Some Linux distros do not enforce the rule that a username must begin with an alpha character. Or even ban special characters.
See the answers to [Why can't Linux usernames begin with numbers?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/why-cant-linux-usernames-begin-with-numbers)
One answer reports that Ubuntu accepts the username `&#%^()!@~*?<>=|`.

> Isn’t not recommended to set the username of Linux start with number?

A username that begins with a (decimal) digit character is not recommended. An alphabetic character is preferred. Then a username is easily distinguishable from a user ID (which is a numeric value).

If you do create an odd username (especially one that looks like a user ID, i.e. a numeric value), you may break or get odd results with some commands.
As you have discovered the `ps -u` command may not always provide the results you want/expect. The `u` option accepts either a username or a user ID. When you provide a username that looks like a user ID (i.e. a number), this option may make the wrong choice and treat the argument as a user ID instead of what it really is.
If you insist on having an unconventional username that does not adhere to strict rules, then you will have to cope with the consequences.

One workaround is, when there is a choice, to always provide the user ID rather than the (ambiguous) username.

Comment: After change the username to alphabets, everything looks well, thx.